# marker.addlistener gets fired up immediately after pageload

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, listener, onclicklistener

This is the code I have, based on the example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple , but instead of zooming in when clicked on a marker, I want to show a messagebox (`alert()`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple click event - modified</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to show alert'
  });

  marker.addListener('click', alert('Hello World!'));
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap" async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course, instead of `YOUR_API_KEY` , I filled in my own API key from Google Maps API v3.

Whenever I load this page, the alert shows as soon as the page is loaded, and clicking on the marker has no effect at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `addlistener`, the command for the messagebox has to be in between a `function() { ... }`:

```
marker.addListener(   'click', function() {  alert('Hello World!');  }    );
```

Will solve the problem!